# Nginx configuration for conditional domain redirect

Tags: nginx

How can I configure nginx  to redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com only if url's first part does not contain the word api

mydomain.com must redirect to www.mydomain.com

mydomain.com/someapi/ request must not redirect to www.mydomain.com

Comment: If you update your question and add your `nginx` server configuration, it will be easier to offer specific advice.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Changed the title. Thanks

Comment: A combination of `location / { return http://www.example.com; }` and `location ~* api { ... }`. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the conditional redirect using the following nginx configuration:

```
location / {
      if ($host = 'example.com' ) {
           rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
      }

}

location ~ ^/(.*api)/{
      #Here I do proxy pass to my app server
}
```